# how to set InstallerPackageName

Tags: java, android, google-play

i want to set my own InstallerPackageName like play store sends com.android.veding,     amaozn sends some different one . how i can set my own for my app so that  when i call getInstallerPackageName i can get it .
 i gone through with [Can PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName() tell me that my app was installed from Amazon app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289748/can-packagemanager-getinstallerpackagename-tell-me-that-my-app-was-installed-f)

Answer (score 0):

The package name which have defined will be identified from your `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `manifest` tag. Whichever the default package name you have defined in the `package:=" field your application will be directly identified by that package only.

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.packagename"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >
```