# How do I differentiate from which store app is installed from i.e Baidu Store / Google Play Store?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-services, baidu, baidu-map

My app. is deployed in Play Store as well as Baidu Store. For notificatiions, need to differentiate from where app. is installed.

When I used getInstallerPackageName() method, Redmi Note 3 returns correct value but HTC returns null.

Why is this difference observed ?

Is there any other better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293534/2724879
i suggest that when its null then its from Baidu and when its `com.android.vending` then its from google xD

Comment: I do agree but if I want to deploy in multiple China Stores .. that will be difficult .. right ? .. any other better way ?

Comment: I do believe so since not all stores are adding the package naming :/

Comment: in that case, and i am not sure if it fits you. but you can generate different APKs for different stores with some parameter on your API to call your backend something like: myappbackend.com/api?store=china1, myappbackend.com/api?store=china2

Comment: and then you will read that parameter on the back end to know with  which store you are dealing with